# how to divide VS project into different folders for each website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#

I want to have multiple websites within ONE VS 2013 project/solution. I am using a virtual folder/ domain setup to allow multiple websites on ONE host.

I want to have folders for each website like so:

```
website1    
- Content    
- Scripts    
- ...etc

website2    
- Content    
- Scripts    
- ...etc
```

How can I do this? I am sure there are guides on this but I haven't been able to find them. I am using MVC 5.

Comment: Create a solution with multiple projects, one for website 1, and one for website 2.

Comment: Actually I could just use multiple projects! But now my issue is using Areas for an F# project.

Comment: lol posted that right when you were replying. Stephen, do you know if it's possible to have Areas for F#?

Comment: MVC Areas? Just the same as in C# - If you mean the folder-structure on disk / in the solution then you can either edit the fsharp-project or go get F#-Powertools ;) (you'll find it in the Extensions:http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff but I think you need a paid VisualStudio to use those)

Comment: edit the fsharp project in what way? I need details. I do have paid VS and Powertools but the option isnt there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@systemsgotyou, already resolved?

Ensure that 'Folder organization' option is enabled in the F# Power Tools settings:

1. Open [TOOLS]-[Options] dialog in your VS
2. Select [F# Power Tools]-[General] category
3. Ensure that 'Folder organization' is checked
4. Restart VS
5. Open your F# solution/project
6. In the Solution Explorer, right click on the F# project node
7. Choose [F# Power Tools]-[New Folder] item

Also, note that when you manage your files/folders with using the 'Folder organization' function, you need to do that via [F# Power Tools] context menu (especially you shouldn't use "Alt+Up Arrow" or "Alt+Down Arrow" to move your F# folder).
Otherwise you'll get unexpected (and strange) compiler error.